# CSS - Stop Text Wrap in Un-ordered List on Images

Tags: html, css

I have a `<ul>` that's forcing the text to wrap around the images within the `<li>`. What's the best way to format this so I can add as much text as I'd like wihtout having any text-wrap? I can't figure this out.

```
<div id="services_banner"><strong>The Amazing Benefits You Get When You Use Advanced Litho</strong></div>
             <span> <img src="../Img/Edits/banner_edge.png"> </span>    
                <div id="our_services">
                     <ul>

                    <li>
                      <img src="http://www.grifolsorderdesk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/personal_services_icon.png" />
                      <h3>Personal Service</h3>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                         </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="http://www.grifolsorderdesk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/online_quote_icon.png" />
                      <h3>Online Instant Quotes</h3>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
                      </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="http://www.grifolsorderdesk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/convenience_icon_2.png" />
                      <h3>Convenience You Can't Beat</h3>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
                      </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="http://www.grifolsorderdesk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/shipping_icon.png" />
                      <span><h3>Fast & Reliable Shipping</h3>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
                      </p></span>
                    </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="contact_support">

                    <img src="http://www.grifolsorderdesk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/tech_support.png">
                    <div id="call_box">
                    <p><strong>Call (949) 215-9060</strong><br> to talk to one of our printing experts.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is my [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stinkytofu/3keL0znm/4/)

Comment: Is CSS `white-spacing:nowrap;` what you are looking at? Else I did not understand your question

Comment: Do you want the text all on one line? I'm not understanding your question

Comment: On the first example text wraps around the icon image to it's left. I'd like it where it does not wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those images really should be background images, in which case you can position them at the left and then add padding-left on the `<li>` so the text stays clear of the image all together.

I played with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/3keL0znm/7/

Comment: note: some of your background images are scaled incorrectly, so I hackily fixed that using the background-size property.  But it would be better to just recreate those images to begin with.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. Is it better to size the images with CSS or size them originally through their raw file?

Comment: it's better to have the image file created at the correct dimensions to begin with.  That way you won't get any blurriness with scaling issues, and you'll optimize file size by not having the image any bigger than you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then you would like something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/3keL0znm/5/

I have put contents inside a `DIV` tag and changed the display of `DIV` tag to `table-cell`

Comment: If you add more content in the form of Text to the <p> tags it begins to wrap around the image again.

Comment: I added [more `P`](https://jsfiddle.net/3keL0znm/12/) and didn't notice any wrapping. Can you provide an example? Also note to illustrate I have only updated the first `LI` (added contents inside `DIV`). I have not updated any other `LI`

Comment: Odd that it works for you. Whenever i add more content it start to wrap around the icons on it's left. Andi work-around seems to be the best solution so i think i'll stick with that. Thanks anyways! :)